# .htaccess: image not loading on webpage

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am using .htaccess rule to prevent image directory access directly. here is .htaccess code

```
Deny from all
```

and i placed this .htaccess file to image directory.

problem is when i try to access some of the images in webpage it is giving me failed to load image error or you can say image not exist.

```
<img class="highlight-right wow animated" src="/img/spark.png" height="192" width="48" alt="">
```

i want to deny access for people accessing it directly but at least it should work on webpage.

Any advise on this.

**Edit:**
I tried this rule

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost/ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png)$ - [F,NC]
```

and

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|png)$ - [F]
```

But both are not working as images are not showing on the webpage.

Comment: Then you need to make a conditional rule based on the referrer in your .htaccess.  Note that this is far from perfect and can block real visitors and doesn't prevent others from getting it depending on their client's configuration.

Comment: @JuliePelletier Thanks for your comment. I am not that much familiar with .htaccess. Can you explain bit more.

Comment: @CalculatingMachine I would leave your deny rule in place to block all external access, but use PHP to access the file internally. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set your `.htaccess` to block them based on the referrer as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?yoursite.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|png|gif)$ http://yoursite.com/errorImage.jpg [NC,R,L]
```

Note that the `HTTP_REFERER` isn't reliable as it can be changed in the client's browser but it's the simplest and most efficient method available.

A more robust method would require the use of cookies or sessions, but that would increase the server load and therefore reduce the response time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: one question if i have multiple types of files in the directory then can i use * ?

Comment: No.  My answer sets a rule that will give the `errorImage.jpg`  for image files (jpg, png, and gif) if the referrer is not empty and not your site.

Answer (score 1):

> i want to deny access for people accessing it directly but at least it
>   should work on webpage.

**1.** In `.htaccess` use `Deny from all` rule to block all direct access.

**2.** Change your image source links to refer to a PHP script in charge of returning the right image.

```
<img src="/path/to/images.php?f=spark.png">
```

Notice how I passed the image name in a parameter? That's how PHP will know which image is requested. In **images.php** do:

```
$IMG_DIR = '/path/to/images'; //put all protected images here

$img = $_GET['f']; //the file's name, matches the f= parameter in <img>

$img_path = $IMG_DIR."/$img";
if(!is_file($img_path)){ // make sure this image exists
    http_response_code(404); //404 not found error
    exit;
}

$extension = pathinfo($img,PATHINFO_EXTENSION); //eg: "png"
$mimetype = "image/$extension"; //type of image. browser needs this info
$size = filesize($img_path);

//tell the browser what to expect
header("Content-Type: $mimetype");
header("Content-Length: $size");

//send the file to the browser
readfile($img_path);
```

I don't do it here but this approach allows you to restrict access as you wish. You could for instance test whether a user is logged in by looking at `$_SESSION` contents before you decide whether to return the image.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.